# How to use var in parameter?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

how to use `var _latitude` and `var _longitude` like a parameter in my `addOrderRequest()` function? Both of variable must be in String,

all code below, thanks for any help :)

```
_getCurrentLocation() async {
    final position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    var _latitude = position.latitude;
    var _longitude = position.longitude;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              //
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomSheet: Container(
        width: width,
        height: 50.0,
        child: new RaisedButton(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(9, 133, 46, 100),
            onPressed: () async {
                addOrderRequest(titleController.text, zipCodeController.text, cityController.text, streetController.text, phoneNumberController.text, descriptionController.text, _selectedCategory);
                Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OrdersScreen()));

                },
```

my function:

```
  addOrderRequest(String title, zipCode, city, street, phoneNumber, description, category, latitude, longitude) async{
    Map data = {
      "title":title,
      "zipCode":zipCode,
      "city":city,
      "street":street,
      "phoneNumber":phoneNumber,
      "description":description,
      "category":category,
      "latitude":latitude,
      "longitude":longitude
    };

    var jsonResponse;
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/order';
    var response = await http.post(url, body:data);

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      print(jsonResponse);      
    }else{
      throw new Exception("Not send data");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is your addOrderRequest()?

Comment: I add in main psot

Comment: @krupnik...I have edited my answer

Comment: ```Undefined name '_latitude'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.```

Comment: it throw me this error

Comment: Check my update

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the variables to string

```
addOrderRequest(titleController.text, zipCodeController.text, cityController.text, streetController.text, phoneNumberController.text, descriptionController.text, _selectedCategory, _latitude.toString(), _longitude.toString());
```

**EDIT** Declare your variables outside the `_getCurrentLocation` function inside the class.

Like this

```
class YourWidget extends StatelessWidget{
    var _latitude;
    var _longitude;

    _getCurrentLocation() async {
    final position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    _latitude = position.latitude;
    _longitude = position.longitude;
  }
```

Comment: No, it not works, i can't use my variables in this function and i don't know how i can do to use

Comment: As I stated in my update...declare the variables in your widget so they become a global variables

Comment: Ignore the StatelessWidget I created...It was just for illustrating